# Picture Files Show Up As Thumbs.db in Java

Tags: java

I created a directory and then listed the files inside the directory in an array. All the files in the directory are .png files. When I print the array out in the console, the pictures are called thumbs.db

```
public static void PictureOverlay1() throws IOException {
    overlay = ImageIO.read(new File(overlayPath2, ""));
    image = ImageIO.read(new File(imagePath, ""));

    if (!path.exists()) {
        System.out.println("Creating File");
        path.mkdir();
    } else {
        System.out.println("Already Created");

        // create the new image, canvas size is the max. of both image sizes
        int w = Math.max(image.getWidth(), overlay.getWidth());
        int h = Math.max(image.getHeight(), overlay.getHeight());
        BufferedImage combined = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        // paint both images, preserving the alpha channels
        Graphics g = combined.getGraphics();
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        g.drawImage(overlay, 0, 0, null);

        // Save as new image
        ImageIO.write(combined, "PNG", new File("C:/Users/Daniel/Documents/Brain Bang/Coding/Minecraft Modding/New Mods/1.6.4 Television Mod/forge/mcp/src/minecraft/assets/tvmod/textures/blocks/combined.png"));
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the code? how you read the file list?

Comment: Your codes ?? , how do ppl suppose to know your problem when you don't even show your codes..

Comment: Sorry, it's my first question on Stackoverflow

Comment: Can you also show the part in which you print the array?

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

> All the files in the directory are .png files.

I don't think so. Since you have a result called `thumbs.db`, I guess you're on a Windows machine. Windows adds two files into each directory:

- `desktop.ini`

  `thumbs.db`

You should skip these two files (or just every hidden file - Windows automatically marks the files as hidden ones).